# Be D true for logical gates circuit

Tags: xor

Considering the logic circuit shown in figure, for which input values, in A, B, C order, will the output D be true? Justify answer.

Thank you!

[image: Image with logical gates]

Answer (score 0):

D will be `1` for the following inputs:

```
A=0, B=1, C=0 : D=1
A=1, B=0, C=0 : D=1
A=1, B=1, C=0 : D=1
A=0, B=0, C=0 : D=1
A=0, B=0, C=1 : D=1
```

Refer [Basics of logic gates](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_7.html)

Comment: Can you explain me with more details please, so for first gate (OR) i have A - 0, B - 0, C - 0; A - 0, B - 1, C - 1; A - 1, B - 0, C - 1; A - 1, B - 1, C - 1. Right? After this i want to combine B (0, 1, 0, 1) with C for the  AND gate?

Comment: I'm confused by that C value, which I don't know how to combine.

Comment: A and B are inputs for the OR gate and B and C are inputs of AND, find both outputs individually first based on the truth table. The output of the both is fed into NAND gate which is 1 in all cases except 1 1

Comment: Why A=0, B=0, C=0 for D=1 it is not valid? Or A=0, B=0, C=1

Comment: A=0 B=0 C=0 Lets go step by step.  A OR B is 0( 0 or 0) B AND C is 0 ...so NAND's input is 0 0 ..NAND outputs 0 only when both inputs are 1

Comment: Yes, NAND outputs 0 only when both inputs are 1. So in this case both inputs are 0. What is wrong with this case, please? Earlier you gave to me 4 variants.

Comment: You are right .when NAND's input are both 0 it outputs 1. You will have to check with all combinations of A B and C.